# Customize jquery autocomplete combobox css

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, hover

How to customize the jquery autocomplete combobox css so that I can make it look as in the picture for to change its hovering styles?
[image]

Part of my code is

```
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
.ui-autocomplete, .ui-autocomplete:hover,
.ui-menu-item, .ui-menu-item:hover,
.ui-menu-item a, .ui-menu-item a:hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-focus,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    background-color: white;
    text-wrap: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;
}

.custom-combobox-toggle {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin-left: -1px;
padding: 0;
/* support: IE7 */
*height: 1.7em;
*top: 0.1em;
width: 40px;
color: white;
border: thin;
border-color: blue;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    position: absolute;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Image: Existing look

[image]

Comment: You mean a blue focus?

Comment: a blue focus and a font color of white

Comment: Are you having `jquery-ui.css` included on your side?

Comment: Yes,jquery-ui.css is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change CSS for `.ui-state-focus`.
Well, this will work for you:

```
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item {
  background:white;
}
.ui-autocomplete .ui-state-focus {
    background:rgb(39, 108, 255); //Change blue color to your favourite shade
    color:white;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rSmCR/2/)**

Comment: @learning I did not get you... What do you mean by saying so? Does your CSS conflict?

Comment: @learning If this doesn't work you may be having problem somewhere else, otherwise this is how you are going to get it...

Comment: Please find attached pic above, it is not  overriding the existing ui css

Comment: You seem to have a `list-style-image`. You will need to set to `none`. And it will be difficult to modify your CSS without actually seeing what is there. And just adding images is not helping. Can you add a JSfiddle?

Comment: @learning You are including `jquery-ui.css` again in HTML part which will have more preference over CSS, on right side space provided for CSS. So look at http://jsfiddle.net/Bn65y/6/ fiddle now... It is working. In JSFiddle please try use the parts as required HTML for HTML, CSS for CSS and JS for JS...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57397/discussion-between-learning-and-j809).